# Once VirtualBOX DHCP is running windows is running smoother

Tags: performance, operating-systems

My problem is that once I run virtualbox DHCP exe file, windows is running smoother. I have windows 11.

I noticed that when I try to open file explorer and use the mouse drag to select files and folders it feels not smooth at all.

One day I wanted to run android emulator on my PC so I used LDPlayer. I noticed that once I run LDPlayer, selecting files and folders very poor performance. After a long investigation, I have noticed that it's because of VirtualBoxDHCP.exe.

It fixes the issue for some reason.

Information about my specs:

- GTX 1660TI
- i7 9700
- Windows is running without intel HD the only available GPU is Nvidia i don't know why but I think it's related to bios settings or something like this I am using Lenovo motherboard it's pre-built PC from lenovo.
- 16GB RAM 2666
- Asus monitor support freesync but not G-SYNC
- M.2 SSD.

Please can you help me I am very confused if you need any further information please tell me and tell me how to get them.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: (1) Please [edit] and use proper punctuation. The first paragraph looks like one long sentence that makes no sense. I'm sure it can be divided to sentences, but it's your job, not each reader's. Place dots where they should be. (2) This question looks like [your previous one](https://superuser.com/q/1685193/432690) rephrased. Please read [What should I do if no one answers my question?](https://superuser.com/help/no-one-answers) Posting the same question again is not the right thing.

Comment: This question already exists: [Windows 11 get better performance when VBoxNetDHCP.exe is running](https://superuser.com/questions/1685193/windows-11-get-better-performance-when-vboxnetdhcp-exe-is-running)

Comment: VMware does not cause such an issue if VMware is an option for you. It matters not whether VMware is running or not. For that matter, the same with Hyper-V (different machine).

Comment: @John dude normally I know it doesn't but I have tested things hundred times once VirtualBoxDHCP.exe is running the problem vanished, why I don't know this is why I am posting.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski I will take your notes into consideration next time, thank you for the tips.

Comment: @John I don't know if this going to help https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=53EaWYYxsnE but this is a video I have recorded about the issue, the problem is that YouTube allow maximum 60 FPS so you might note any difference I might record another video and upload it to google drive what do you think?

Comment: @John you can download this video file and watch the video I have shown the problem and spoke about it by my voice. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1t5KULsuH9v3QkWzguW3pOmUiX9Ahjnpe/view?usp=share_link don't watch it from google drive itself but download the file in order to be able to run it at 144HZ

Comment: I did go there and can see there is an issue but I am not any farther ahead as to what may be causing it.  Sorrry.

Comment: You might try the following:   Uninstall Virtual Box completely (make sure you have backups of your guest machines).  Restart.   Update all drivers particularly network drivers.  Run TCP/IP Reset.   Restart. Install Virtual Box and test.

Comment: @John actually I don't have virtual box but those android emulator I think they have built-in virtual box version, anyways before I tried to uninstall any android emulator and restart the PC but nothing happened. But what is weird that how TCP/IP reset can affect the performance, the problem is very weird I am really frustrated.